# Issue with ETLUtils and ODCB connection

Tags: r, bigdata, etl, rodbc, ff

I am attempting to connect to an Oracle database, extract my data and put it into a flat file on R. The table has ~ 16 million rows with 25 columns. There are many strings in some of these columns. I am using the RODBC and ETLUtils package in R.

Here is my code:

```
    test<-read.odbc.ffdf(query="select * from meta", 
    odbcConnect.args=list(dsn="XX", uid="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", pwd="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
    test=test,VERBOSE=TRUE)
```

After I run this I am getting the following error:

```
        read.odbc.ffdf 1.. ()  odbc-read=0sec
Error in if (nrow(dat) == 0) { : argument is of length zero
```

I'm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: What is this test argument? There is no test argument when looking at the help of ?read.odbc.ffdf You might also want to check if a connection works using ?odbcConnect before trying out read.odbc.ffdf

Comment: The test argument is the name of the optional ff object to append records to. If I remove test=test argument I get the same error. 

Here is another example of my code:

x<-read.odbc.ffdf(query="select * from meta", 
                     odbcConnect.args=list(dsn="DXX",uid="XXXXXXXXX", pwd="XXXXXXXXX"),VERBOSE=TRUE)

Comment: What does require(RODBC); odbcConnect(dsn="DXX",uid="XXXXXXXXX", pwd="XXXXXXXXX") give you?

Comment: That is how I connect to my database. I use the rODBC package and the odbcConnect function with my DSN, user id and password.

Comment: Yes, and does that work or does it give an error?

Comment: It works. I'm capable of extracting and analyzing data from the database using a query that looks like this:  sqlQuery(database, "select * from table").

Comment: And does sqlQuery(database, "select * from meta") return records or does it return 0 records.